# Transforming Excel constrained optimization in R

Tags: r, excel, optimization

I have a dataframe in Excel which looks like this:

In columns **A**, **B** & **C** are stock returns. Column **D** contins Market returns.
In cells **E1**, **F1** & **G1**, I calculate the slope (beta) of X=a+b_R (b1, b2 & b3 on R which is the variable in col. **D**).
In cells **E2**, **F2** & **G2** are weights w1, w2 & w3.

In column **H**, I calculate an index as `MyR = A*w1 + B*w2 + C*w3`

In solver, the objective function to minimize is the variance of MyR, changing w1, w2, w3 subject to the following constrains:

```
w1+w2+w3=1
cor(R,MyR)=0
w1*b1+w2*b2+w3*b3=0
sum(Rm)>0
```

In excel the problem solved easily except that It is not practical to repeat it for several periods.

It is possible to set up and solve this problem in R?

Comment: hey welcome to stackoverflow, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can try out the code

Comment: you could use vba to move the data into pre-set cells and then call the solver, then copy/pastespecial the results out and repeat...

Comment: mischva11, I have upload a minimal example of the problem (please find the file in ... goo.gl/5NdzBE) .

Comment: Solar, I have read some approaches to run solver automaically in excel. The problem is that I am not expert in excel, besides I work in linux and therefore I prefer to solve the problem in R, matlab or octave.

Comment: Can you [edit] a minimal example of the data data as text into the body of your question? Most people are rightly worried about downloading an unknown file from a stranger on the internet.